# Why only "it", not "this" or "that"?

Tags: pronouns, demonstrative-pronouns

> **It** seems you are incompetent to achieve our goal.
>
> The chocolate tastes sweet when **it** is tasted. (Quasi-passive voice)
>
> **It** is raining.
>
> Your request, **it** is under consideration now.

and so on, so on and so on...

These constructions, if you observe, can easily understand the similarity among them- *it* is using "it" everytime. Now my question is why is *it* "it" always? Why is not *this* "this" or "that"?

Comment: If there are anymore appropriate tags I left, please feel free to re-tag the question.

Comment: What is the *quasi-passive voice*?

Comment: @snailboat, Well, it's like IIRC if someone gives you to change the voice of "The chocolate tastes sweet" then it changes to in passive voice "The chocolate tastes sweet when it is tasted.' In this [blogpost](http://enggrammar2009.blogspot.in/2009/12/active-voice-when-verb-of-subject-is.html) I found some examples.

Comment: Oh, I see!  (The books I've read don't use that term.)  In any case, if you'd like your sentence to fit the pattern outlined in that blog post, your example should read *"The chocolate **is** sweet when it is tasted."*

Comment: @Mistu4u The term I've encountered is *ergative*, as in *John is cooking the risotto ... The risotto is cooking*. But *taste* is a bit different: it alternates between transitive and copulative rather than transitive and ergative. In any case, only a transitive verb may be passivized.

Comment: @snailboat, Again seems like an Indian and surrounding people's sue this term. I just saw now the author of that blog is from Bangladesh.

Answer (score 3):

*This* and *that* are demonstrative pronouns: they are employed to ‘point at’ particular entities, usually to **distinguish** them from other entities.

In your first and fourth sentences, *it* is ‘expletive’—that is, *it* has no referent, it is present only to fill a syntactic ‘slot’ which would otherwise be intolerably empty. There is no entity pointed at, so it would be inappropriate to employ *this* or *that*. Only *it* is permitted to fill this ‘dummy’ role, just as only *DO* is permitted to fill the role of dummy auxiliary in questions. Any other pronoun raises the unanswerable question “What is its referent?”

> That seems you are incompetent. ... ***What** seems you are incompetent?*
> This is raining. ... ***What** is raining?*

In your other sentences, however, *it* is an ordinary personal pronoun, and it is possible to imagine circumstances under which it would be appropriate to employ a demonstrative.

> I may say that your report is deeply appreciated, and your observations have been well received. As for your request, **that** is still under consideration; but I don’t think there will be any difficulty about it.
>
> Respondents characterize the lemon drops and the peppermints as primarily “sharp”. The chocolate, however, is rated “sweet” when **this** is tasted.

Note that the ‘chocolate” sentence is awkward; the determiner (*the*) and the generic present tense (*is*) both struggle against use of the demonstrative. But it’s possible.

Comment: I see, so English Grammar has said the rules for using "this", "that" or "it". I guessed before posting the question that "it" is used merely because people use it.

Comment: @Mistu4u Well, but that's true of everything in any language! :)