# Change the voice of "The rose smells sweet"

Tags: passive-voice, middle-voice

I am a student in 10th class, and I am stuck on a homework problem.

> Change the voice:
>
> ```
> "The rose smells sweet."
> ```

I thought a lot but I couldn't get an answer. I think that the voice of this sentence cannot be changed, but I am not sure and I thought that it would be better if I ask here first.

Comment: This is part of a class of verbs that represent behaviours, and hence are difficult to passivise because, strictly speaking, they don't really have an agent as other verbs do. Other examples include _smile_, _laugh_, _sing_, _cry_ __if__ they occur without an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked my teacher and she told me that the answer was:

> "The rose is sweet when smelt."

Comment: This is not a passive version of the original sentence.

Comment: This is the correct passive voice.  "Smell" is a quasi passive verb.  (Honestly as a native speaker I wouldn't have known this but for google.)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Although there is a passive in Kartik's sentence, snailplane is quite right: Kartik's sentence is not derivable from OP's.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis The term "quasi-passive verb" or "quasi-passive voice" is intriguing. I tried searching the web to find at least one authoritative source, but couldn't find even one. Most of the results (of this "quasi-passive voice") I found are from ESL websites, blog posts, or discussion forums. The rest are the analysis results likely to be written by non-native English speaking linguists. The term was mentioned [here on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10991/3281) too. I'm now curious to learn what English linguists said on this "quasi-passive".

Comment: @DamkerngT. *A grammar of Contemporary English* (Quirk & al) has a whole page on quasi-passives (a book not primarily meant for ESL learners). To put it very briefly they represent a "mixed class whose members have both verbal and adjectival properties." First time I ever read that page in the 40 years I've had the book, but I've used quasi-passives for longer that 40 years. If discussed at all I don't think ELL is the best place.

Comment: @Laure Thank you very much for your invaluable information. I can now be rest assured that the term "quasi-passive" is valid.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried this but don't know it is right or not.

> Smell of rose is sweet

Comment: This is not a passive voice. It is also incorrect because of missing articles, it should be “The smell of a rose is sweet.” or “The smell of the rose is sweet.”.